# Regular expression to replace line feeds with a space only if the break is in certain keyword pair

Tags: regex, replace, newline, whitespace, linefeed

I'm trying to write a regular expression that replaces line feeds between certain areas of a text file, but only on certain keywords (beginning keyword and end keyword are not paired) but not having much luck past the first part.

Example input:

```
QUESTION NO: 1130

May a health plan require a provider to use a health care clearinghouse to conduct a HIPAA- covered transaction, or must the health plan acquire the ability to conduct the transaction directly with those providers capable of conducting direct transactions?

A. A health plan may conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse, and may require a
provider to conduct covered transactions with it through a clearinghouse. But the incremental cost of doing so must be borne by the health plan. It is a cost-benefit decision on the part of the health plan whether to acquire the ability to conduct HIPAA transactions directly with other entities, or to require use of a clearinghouse.  B. A health plan may not conduct it's covered transactions through a clearinghouse
C. A health plan may after taking specific permission from HIPAA authorities conduct its covered
transactions through a clearinghouse  D. is not as per HIPAA allowed to require provider to conduct covered transactions with it through

a clearinghouse

Answer: A

Explanation: Personnel security always have to deal more with Operational controls, Operational
controls provide the guidelines and the correct procedures to implement the different operations. Management controls are usually used only by managers. Human resources and Technical Controls are not related to personal security as the question states. See the different control definitions in your CISSP documentation.
```

Example output:

```
QUESTION NO: 1130

May a health plan require a provider to use a health care clearinghouse to conduct a HIPAA- covered transaction, or must the health plan acquire the ability to conduct the transaction directly with those providers capable of conducting direct transactions?

A. A health plan may conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse, and may require a provider to conduct covered transactions with it through a clearinghouse. But the incremental cost of doing so must be borne by the health plan. It is a cost-benefit decision on the part of the health plan whether to acquire the ability to conduct HIPAA transactions directly with other entities, or to require use of a clearinghouse.
B. A health plan may not conduct it's covered transactions through a clearinghouse
C. A health plan may after taking specific permission from HIPAA authorities conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse
D. is not as per HIPAA allowed to require provider to conduct covered transactions with it through a clearinghouse

Answer: A

Explanation: A View is a display of one or more table shows that shows the table data. You can even retrieve part of the table and display the same to the user. Before a user is able to use a view, they must have both, permission on the view and all dependent objects. Views can also be used to implement security, for example you can create a view that only shows 3 of 5 columns contained in a table. Views are not used to provide integrity you can use constraints, rule or other components of database systems.
```

My ideal situation is, the text content between `"A. "` and `"Answer: "` get removed the linefeed and the rest of text keep untouched.

Comment: What language are you using ?

Comment: @HamZaDzCyberDeV: I personally use Python / PHP / Javascript, but anything work in RegexBuddy would be fine.

Answer (score 0):

In Python you could do this;

**WARNING**: This is not safe to rely on 100%. If `X.` occurs in the normal sentences, you *will* be "screwed".

```
import re

subject = '''A. A health plan may conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse, and may require a
provider to conduct covered transactions with it through a clearinghouse. But the incremental cost of doing so must be borne by the health plan. It is a cost-benefit decision on the part of the health plan whether to acquire the ability to conduct HIPAA transactions directly with other entities, or to require use of a clearinghouse.  B. A health plan may not conduct it's covered transactions through a clearinghouse
C. A health plan may after taking specific permission from HIPAA authorities conduct its covered
transactions through a clearinghouse  D. is not as per HIPAA allowed to require provider to conduct covered transactions with it through'''

result = re.findall(r'([A-Z]\. )(.*?)(?=[A-Z]\. |$)', subject, re.S)

new_string = ''

if len(result) > 0:
    for entry in result:
        new_string += entry[0] + entry[1].strip().replace('\n', ' ') + '\n'
else:
    print 'Nothing found'

print new_string
```

The positive lookahead looks for either a new `X.` or the end of the string. This might *not* work tho if you match your whole string. In that case let it keep looking until it finds `Answer:` and strip of the trailing newlines (`(?=[A-Z]\. |\n+Answer: \w)`).

**Terminal Output**

```
iMac2011:Desktop allendar$ python test.py
A. A health plan may conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse, and may require a provider to conduct covered transactions with it through a clearinghouse. But the incremental cost of doing so must be borne by the health plan. It is a cost-benefit decision on the part of the health plan whether to acquire the ability to conduct HIPAA transactions directly with other entities, or to require use of a clearinghouse.
B. A health plan may not conduct it's covered transactions through a clearinghouse
C. A health plan may after taking specific permission from HIPAA authorities conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse
D. is not as per HIPAA allowed to require provider to conduct covered transactions with it through
```

**Update code**

```
import re

subject = '''QUESTION NO: 1130

May a health plan require a provider to use a health care clearinghouse to conduct a HIPAA- covered transaction, or must the health plan acquire the ability to conduct the transaction directly with those providers capable of conducting direct transactions?

A. A health plan may conduct its covered transactions through a clearinghouse, and may require a
provider to conduct covered transactions with it through a clearinghouse. But the incremental cost of doing so must be borne by the health plan. It is a cost-benefit decision on the part of the health plan whether to acquire the ability to conduct HIPAA transactions directly with other entities, or to require use of a clearinghouse.  B. A health plan may not conduct it's covered transactions through a clearinghouse
C. A health plan may after taking specific permission from HIPAA authorities conduct its covered
transactions through a clearinghouse  D. is not as per HIPAA allowed to require provider to conduct covered transactions with it through

a clearinghouse

Answer: A

Explanation: Personnel security always have to deal more with Operational controls, Operational
controls provide the guidelines and the correct procedures to implement the different operations. Management controls are usually used only by managers. Human resources and Technical Controls are not related to personal security as the question states. See the different control definitions in your CISSP documentation.'''

result = re.findall(r'([A-Z]\. )(.*?)(?=[A-Z]\. |\n{1,}Answer:\s\w+\s?\n+)', subject, re.S)


new_string = ''

if len(result) > 0:
    for entry in result:
        new_string += entry[0] + entry[1].strip().replace('\n\n', ' ').replace('\n', ' ') + '\n'
else:
    print 'Nothing found'

print new_string
```

Comment: Partially working, but I have some glitch in 'Explanation'. The sample text above is modified.

Comment: Try the updated code. I'm not what you mean with "modified". Do you mean my own edit of the sample regex (`(?=[A-Z]\. |\n{2,}Answer|\n+Answer: \w)`)?